# Chaining Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have two jobs defined in two different xmls. Say Job A & Job B.
I need to call Job B on successful completion of Job A.
What is the best approach of doing this.
I am pretty new to spring-batch so looking for the best approach to handle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137215/how-to-run-spring-batch-jobs-in-parallel/25138506#25138506

Answer (score 1):

You can create a superjob and execute your job A and Job B as steps in this super job specifying that Job B should be executed on successful completion of Job A