# Spring batch configuration with JobStep fails to load

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I'm trying to chain jobs in SpringBatch by using `JobStep`s (as recommended here: [How to run spring batch jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137215/how-to-run-spring-batch-jobs-in-parallel/25138506#25138506)).

```
@Configuration
public class JobFlowConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Step jobStep1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, Job job1) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("jobStep1").job(job1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step jobStep2(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, Job job2) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("jobStep2").job(job2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job flowJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step jobStep1, Step jobStep2) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("flowJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(jobStep1).next(jobStep2).end().build();
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is, that when ever the configuration with this job definition is loaded I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'job1': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
```

Without this configuration all referenced jobs work fine and the app (SpringBatch Admin running with SpringBoot) loads without any issues.

I'm sure there is no circular reference between any of these configurations. For me it looks like first all `Step`s get loaded before any `Job`s but then it fails because there is a `Step`(jobStep1) which depends on a `Job`(job1).

I also tied to exclude this configuration class from component scanning and then load it explicitly after the component scan.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

update:

here is an example application with the exact problem https://github.com/imod/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot/tree/jobstep_example (use correct branch: `jobstep_example`)

The class/configuration causing the issue is `ImportUserFlowJobConfiguration`

To start `SpringBatchAdmin` to see the issue.

---

update: a job is created like this:

```
@Bean
public Job job1(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1) {
   return jobs.get("job1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(s1).end().build();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definitions for `job1`, etc?

Comment: Michael, I added a link to a small application showing the problem